# What happens when a question is migrated to MSE?

Tags: discussion, migration

When a question is closed as off topic and migrated, will it no longer appear in MO, or will it appear in MO with a note saying it has been migrated?

Similarly, in MSE, will it say "migrated from MO" or just appear as a standard question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title here on MO will appear with the text `[migrated]` appended to it. (Compare to the addition of `[closed]` for otherwise closed questions.) It will also have a banner below the question that states that it is migrated to Math.SE.

The question will appear on Math.SE with a banner *below* the question (near where the 'add comment' link is) that states that it was migrated in from MO.

Nothing has yet been migrated, so I cannot show you an exact demonstration. But for what it would look like try [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427421/vector-problem) which was migrated from Physics.SE to Math.SE.

---

And [here's an example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134674/proving-that-the-set-of-lfloor-n-3-rfloor1-partial-latin-squares-given-by-p) on our site of the reverse migration.

Comment: A note: If a migrated question is closed as anything but a duplicate, the migration is rejected; both posts get locked, and the post on MO will just say that it was closed as Off Topic

Comment: Here's an example:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134238/enlarging-an-ellipses-along-normal-direction?noredirect=1

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429110/enlarging-an-ellipses-along-normal-direction

Comment: Perhaps it is also worth mentioning that the migrated question is deleted on the original site after 30 days. Meta.SO: [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)